# Fixed field and prime field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

[image]

I know that F is subset of field K. We know Any $\sigma$ in $Aut(K)$ 
if $\alpha$ is in F then $\alpha^{-1}$ is in F since identity goes to identity and
$\sigma(\alpha.\alpha^{-1})$= $\sigma(1) =1 $ ;
 $\sigma(\alpha).\sigma(\alpha^{-1})$ = $\alpha.\sigma(\alpha^{-1})$ =1 so $\sigma(\alpha^{-1})=\alpha^{-1}$  so inverse for every element exist in Fixed automorphisam. Now how to show it contains prime subfield of $K$?

Comment: Your proof that $F$ is a subfield is incomplete.

Comment: why it is incomplete @lhf?

Comment: You need to prove that $F$ is closed under addition. multiplication, negatives, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given **any** field $K$ and **any** subfield $F$, $F$ contains the prime subfield of $K$, since the prime subfield of $K$ is its smallest subfield.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The prime field of $K$ is contained in *every* subfield of $K$.